# EC2 and setting up MYSQL Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, snapshot, aws, amazon-ec2

my database size is very big around 100gb and when I restore it takes 3 days to restore. I am using amazon ec2.

My question is I want to setup a new slave to MYSQL master, can I take a snapshot of the Master and create a new instance using the snapshot and then enable replication in between.Given that I take log position before the snapshot and `my.cnf` changes as required. Snapshot is very fast and takes 1-2hours to create a new machine, whereas `mysqldump` is taking very very long.

I was just worried if replication works using above method, can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1):

on Amazon system you can use following steps to setup replication for MySQL

- Choose a low/off production window
- Note Master co-ordinate using show master status
- You may consider using flush tables with read-lock, just to make sure you are sure that your co-ordinates doesn't change while you are creating snap shot
- take snap shot and restore
- Change server-id and relay log and issue change master

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to drop mysqldump and move to Percona Xtrabackup. It will give you a filesystem level backup that can be made online. Restoring those backups will be orders of magnitude faster.